# Getting two consecutive frames from camera in Processing

Tags: image, video, camera, processing, frames

I've been trying a couple of ways to achieve this using Processing, but each time, it doesn't get some that are perfectly consecutive. Would anyone know the "right way" of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What exactly do you mean when you say it doesn't get that? What does it get instead? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Malo Maisonneuve it probably depends on what's going on in front of the camera, right ? If there is no motion, two consecutive frames will look identical. As Kevin, mentioned, please be more specific. What does "perfectly consecutive" frames mean to you ?

Comment: I can't post any Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example this time because I haven't got any. My question is broader than that. I'm just trying to store in two different variables two consecutive frames of a video thread recorded in live by a camera. At every attempt I made, I was either getting two frames that weren't consecutive, or two frames that were the same. Not that there weren't any movement, but even the noise of the camera on the two frames was identical. So would you have by any chance any idea of a small piece of code that could do that? (I hope I was clear, if not, tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it should be a matter of listening to the [captureEvent()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/captureEvent_.html) to get a new frame and keep track if the first frame was previously recorded, if so recorded the second one afterwards.

Here's a basic commented sketch to illustrate the point (press any key to grab another pair of frames):

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture camera;

PImage firstFrame;
PImage secondFrame;

void setup(){
  size(1920,480);

  camera = new Capture(this,640,480);
  camera.start();
}
void draw(){
  image(camera,0,0);
  if(firstFrame != null){
    image(firstFrame,640,0);
  }
  if(secondFrame != null){
    image(secondFrame,1280,0);
  }
}
//this is the callback from the video library when a new camera frame is available
void captureEvent(Capture c){
  //read a new frame
  c.read();
  //if the first frame wasn't recorded yet, record(copy) it's pixels
  if(firstFrame == null){
    firstFrame = c.get();
  }
  //same for the second frame, but check if the first frame has been recorded first
  if(firstFrame != null && secondFrame == null){
    secondFrame = c.get();
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  //reset consecutive frames on keypress
  firstFrame = secondFrame = null;
}
```

In theory (as you can see in the [Processing Video Library's source code](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/blob/master/src/processing/video/Capture.java#L1192)), captureEvent is fired only when a new camera sample is ready.
In practice, you will find that two consecutive frames may look identical (even though they could be a split second apart in time), even noise as you pointed out in your comments.

It feels like what you're after is a frame that is consecutive, but different enough from the previous. If that's the case you can have a play with the [FrameDifferencing example](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/blob/master/examples/Capture/FrameDifferencing/FrameDifferencing.pde) (**Processing > Examples > Libraries > Video > Capture > FrameDifferencing**)

Here's a modified version of the above sketch, using Golan Levin's FrameDifferencing code to only grab a second frame if it's different by a little bit:

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture camera;

PImage firstFrame;
PImage secondFrame;
PImage diff;

void setup(){
  size(1920,960);

  camera = new Capture(this,640,480);
  camera.start();

  diff = createImage(640,480,RGB);
}
void draw(){
  image(camera,0,0);
  if(firstFrame != null){
    image(firstFrame,640,0);
  }
  if(secondFrame != null){
    image(secondFrame,1280,0);
  }
  image(diff,0,480);
}
//this is the callback from the video library when a new camera frame is available
void captureEvent(Capture c){
  //read a new frame
  c.read();
  //if the first frame wasn't recorded yet, record(copy) it's pixels
  if(firstFrame == null){
    firstFrame = c.get();
    println("recorded first frame at",new java.util.Date());
  }
  //same for the second frame, but check if the first frame has been recorded first
  if(firstFrame != null && secondFrame == null){
    //if the difference between the first frame cand the current frame is even ever so slightly off, record the second frame
    if(difference(firstFrame,camera) > 100){
      secondFrame = c.get();
    }
  }

}

int difference(PImage first,PImage second){
  final int numPixels = 640*480;
  camera.loadPixels();
  int movementSum = 0; // Amount of movement in the frame
  for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) { // For each pixel in the video frame...
    color currColor = first.pixels[i];
    color prevColor = second.pixels[i];
    // Extract the red, green, and blue components from current pixel
    int currR = (currColor >> 16) & 0xFF; // Like red(), but faster
    int currG = (currColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int currB = currColor & 0xFF;
    // Extract red, green, and blue components from previous pixel
    int prevR = (prevColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int prevG = (prevColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int prevB = prevColor & 0xFF;
    // Compute the difference of the red, green, and blue values
    int diffR = abs(currR - prevR);
    int diffG = abs(currG - prevG);
    int diffB = abs(currB - prevB);
    // Render the difference image to the screen
    diff.pixels[i] = color(diffR, diffG, diffB);
    // Add these differences to the running tally
    movementSum += diffR + diffG + diffB;
  }
  diff.updatePixels();
  return movementSum;
}

void keyPressed(){
  //reset consecutive frames on keypress
  firstFrame = secondFrame = null;
}
```

In the example above 100 is an arbitrary value.
The max would be `255*3*640*480` (0-255 per channel * number of channels * width * height)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the KetaiCamera [sources](https://github.com/ketai/ketai/blob/master/src/ketai/camera/KetaiCamera.java) and [issue reports](https://github.com/ketai/ketai/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+camera), especially [this one](https://github.com/ketai/ketai/issues/7). Unfortunately this code is not built to provide real time camera frames.

You can try to take the [AndroidCapture](https://github.com/onlylemi/processing-android-capture) project as a starter, and modify the native Android [class](https://github.com/onlylemi/AndroidCapture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/onlylemi/android/capture/PreviewSurface.java) to achieve your goal.

Comment: I'm not actually using his camera because it's more of a computer using a webcam. But is this issue general, or does it only apply to this specific camera function KetaiCamera (I tried using the Capture function in processing)?

Comment: If I interpret [this discussion](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6239/looking-for-a-capture-alternative-that-will-run-on-android-any-suggestions) correctly, there is no ready-to-use class that can keep up with the true frame rate of an Android camera. You should look into the [AndroidCapture](https://github.com/onlylemi/processing-android-capture) class, but to produce frames reliably, you must roll up your virtual sleeves and build a dedicated implementation using Android SDK.